# Invalid arguments in classes

Tags: c++, class, arguments

```
char* n=m.getName();
```

I get the following error `Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: char * getName() '` for the above instruction.What am I missing?

```
char* Medicine::getName() 
{
    return this->name;
}
```

`name` is of declared as `char name[50];` and`m` is `const Medicine& m`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `m` is `const`, then only `const` methods can be called on it. Maybe you can change your method to

```
const char* Medicine::getName() const;
```

and use it like this:

```
const char* n=m.getName();
```

Although you might consider using an `std::string` data member instead of an array of `char`.

Comment: If there are good reasons for the down-vote, I'd like to hear them. I am more happy to fix errors in this answer or clarify it if necessary.

Comment: Thanks,I'll go looking for some `string` tutorials

Comment: @juanchopanza Someone downvoted this answer? Seriously? Wh... what? Why?!

Answer (score 0):

Please note that if the member variable is const, only const member function can access this. Same for static, i.e if the member variable is static only a static member can access that.